# Invantive Control MSI fails with error status 1602

Tags: windows-installer, invantive-control

When installing Invantive Control for Excel using the MSI installer, it ends with the message:

> Invantive Control for Excel Setup Wizard was interrupted

In the event log it says in chronological order:

> Invantive Control for Excel -- Installation failed.
>
> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Invantive
>   Control for Excel. Product Version: 1.17.11506. Product Language:
>   1033. Manufacturer: Invantive Software B.V.. Installation success or error status: 1602.

There are no further hints available. How can I analyze this problem to get a root cause?

Answer (score 0):

MSI offers some logging which can be activated.

To activate it for all installations, you will need to create a key named `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer` when not present. Put a string value in Logging with the value 'voicewarmup'. 'Voicewarmup' seems to have nothing to do with singing, but is just a list of options glued together in an easy to remember phrase:

- v: verbose messages
- o: out-of-disk messages
- i: status messages
- c: initial ui parameters
- e: all error messages
- w: non-fatal warning messages
- a: startup messages
- r: action-specific record messages
- m: out-of memory or fatal exit messages
- u: user request messages
- p: terminal property messages

When running msiexec, you can also specify logging as [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), such as:

```
msiexec /i "Invantive Control for Excel.msi" /L*v "file.log"
```

with `v` again standing for verbose output.

After running the installer, please check the contents of the folder %TEMP%.